# Where can I ask a question about file types

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question about what programs to use to open outdated file types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SuperUser](http://superuser.com) would be best for more general computer questions, but asking for product recommendations is off-topic there, so it is not a good fit.

Maybe [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is better.

Comment: Thanks - I could probably format it in such a way that it isn't a product recommendation request.

Comment: That is at your own risk of course, but an option to try.